# Point apache-spark to Python 3.8 instead of Python 2.7 in Mac

Tags: python, macos, apache-spark, pyspark

I have apache-spark installed on my Mac which is running Big Sur version 11.1.

When I run the command "pyspark" in my terminal, it raises the warning below:

> WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended.  This version is included in
> macOS for compatibility with legacy software.  Future versions of
> macOS will not include Python 2.7.  Instead, it is recommended that
> you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.

I have python 3.8 installed on my system. Does anyone know how I can point apache-spark to that instead? I was under the impression that I have to modify my .bash_profile, but I couldn't find that file in my system.

Comment: How did you install spark?

Comment: you can set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` environment variables to python3.8

Comment: i installed using this website: https://medium.com/macoclock/how-to-install-apache-pyspark-on-macbook-pro-4a9249f0d823

Comment: mck, let me try to do that. if you have a how-to that you can point me to, that will be helpful. thanks.